# Restful web service for searching in c#

Tags: android, c#-4.0, restful-url

I want to create a Restful web service in c#,which take the ***Searching Keyword*** from android app and search into the database and return the result into the json format.so can you suggest me some links which help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WCF in C# to build the web service and cosume them as json using HttpGet. WCF provide good option for rest based web service.

Here link for tutorial for wcf.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wcf/

Comment: can you provide me some link which contain the code

Comment: Here are some useful link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358867/WCF-and-Android-Part-I http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361107/WCF-and-Android-Part-II

Comment: can you give me some you tube link or videos links.